# Rails 4.1 Enum limit return in fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, nested-attributes, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have a simple nested form where it displays the fields for a user's dashboard and the nested attributes for the dashboard's tiles (aka widgets). I'm using Rails 4.1 and would like to only display the `:tiles` for the `enum :middle_column (whose value is 2)`. What would be the proper syntax for changing the `f.simple_fields_for :tiles do |builder|` to limit to the `enum :middle_column`?

```
<%= simple_form_for [@user, @dashboard] do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :tiles do |builder| %>
    <%= render "widgets/#{builder.object.widget.function}_fields", f: builder %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me. I can pass a second argument to the `simple_fields_for` which will limit the results.

`f.simple_fields_for :tiles, f.object.tiles.where(position: Tile.positions[:middle_column]) do |builder|`